# Unable to redirect all requests that are not to index.php, resources or robots.txt in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've changed the directory structure of basic Codeigniter. Now I'm trying to redirect all requests that are not to index.php, resources or robots.txt but my `.htaccess` is not working. Here is my directory structure

- project

  - application
  - public

    - .htaccess
    - index.php
  - system

My .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The meaning is not to remove the index.php but to redirect all requests to it that are not to index.php, resources or robots.txt

Comment: If you add some information about how you are serving this page (apache) it would help. It might be that your rewrite module is not enabled.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I've checked my rewrite module is enabled in Loaded Modules

Comment: so what happens, do you get errors, redirection, what happens?

Comment: @RonniSkansing I'm getting a 404

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If it doesnt work,

Check whether rewrite module is not enabled or not

Comment: Thank you @satdev86 but its not working. I'm getting a 404. Also rewrite module is enabled

Comment: May i know why did you keep .htaccess and index.php inside public folder? As per CI file structure, the index.php and .htaccess lies in the root folder

Comment: so what do you suggest? Where should I place my .htaccess and why?

Comment: I edited my previous comment, Please remove them from public folder and keep it in in the root directory of your app

Comment: Is it necessary because I want to separate them from the files which allowed to access by the public. Thats why I made such directory structure

Comment: In that case.. may i know how do you try to access your app.. isthat
http://localhost/appname/public/

Comment: yes I'm trying to access my app by http://localhost/app/public. This brings up the welcome screen but as soon as I change it to http://localhost/app/public/welcome it gives me 404

Comment: Did you changed the application path and system path in index.php.. as you had changed the placement of index.php. you also need to do this change, can you please cross check it..
$application_folder = '../application';
$system_path = '../system';

Comment: Also, check your file and directory permission, it should be 644. So apply this from your root directory
chmod -R 0644 application system public/index.php

Comment: yes, that was the first change I made in the index.php. I changed paths to $system_path = '../system'; and $application_folder = '../application';

Comment: see my recent comment.
chmod -R 0644 application system public/index.php

Comment: Please check your file permissions then

Comment: How to do that because I'm using xp sp3 and there is no option to check file permission